# Asus G50 OLED Change

Tags: laptop

The ASUS G50VT has an OLED above the keyboard that displays "Republic Of Gamers". I would like to completely remove this msg. Either set it blank or display useful information like battery life or CPU utilization. 
I installed Windows 8 fresh and Direct Console does nothing. I have looked at LCDHype and while it does change the LCD it has no useful scripts(I could probably download them) and doesn't make the changes permanent(reverts back original on reboot).

Answer (score 0):

The original Asus laptop software came with an option to customize the message, but it was only permanent in the sense that when Windows booted up, it would change it. You could display a custom message, have instant messages piped into it, or display computer stats.

From this [forum thread](http://www.overclock.net/t/1083412/asus-g50vt-second-display-small-led):

> Install these utilities from the CD to get the functionality
>   P4GX
>   KBFilter
>   ATKACPI
>   AGFNEX